# How can i verify before dropping a text to a droppable div, that the div already contains the text or not?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a lots of draggable paragraph like: Course1, Course2, Course3, Course2, Course1. These  all Courses are draggable. And i have a div which is droppable. Now i want to drag a course and drop to the div. But the thing is, the div will only accept the Course to drop if the course is already not present inside the div.

Now how can i check the draggable text and the droppable div's text while i am dropping a Course ?

I already implement the think, but i can not find any way to compare the text while dropping

Comment: can you try some code? and is it drag and drop already working and only drag text exist or not checking point pending.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.